# Playing audio with touchesBegan XCode

Tags: xcode, touchesbegan

I'm new to StackOverflow, (Just signed up) and with that, pretty darn new to coding! I've been using YouTube videos to learn how to code, and I'm currently trying to make a game similar to Flappy Bird. Not to publish, merely to experiment.

I've completed the coding for the game, however I want to add a sound effect when any area on the screen is touched, but only at a certain time (After the 'start' button is pressed).

I tried this with a button fitted to the whole ViewVontroller, but it disallowed me to actually play the game....

I heard touchesBegan would make this work, so please help me.

Thank you in advance =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should work fine :

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (startButtonPressed) {
        //Play sound 
    }
}
```

> Tells the receiver when one or more fingers touch down in a view or
>   window.

Official documentation [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan:withEvent:)

You can also do it with StoryBoard :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can you let me know how this code works please?

Comment: On a touch on screen, this function will be call automatically.